# BottomSheetDialogFragment keeps reappearing at onResume

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I show a BottomSheetDialogFragment with the following code:

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new MediaAddFragment();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onResume();
            MainActivity.updateMediaButtons();
        }
    });
```

To close it, I call dismiss() from within the Fragment. With that, it gets dismissed, but is shown again if the app gets resumed, which is not my intention.

I would be glad if someone could help me with this. I already scanned various tutorials on how to properly use those BottomSheetDialogFragments, but I cannot find my error.

Incidentally, I don't have any code in onResume to test it.

Comment: where do you call this code?

Comment: I call it from another Fragment, from an onclicklistener

Answer (score 5):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I found my error, I was overwriting the onDismissListener of the BottomSheetDialogFragment in the calling fragment. Now it works as expected.

```
bottomSheetDialogFragment2.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // Adding the following line fixed the problem for me
                    bottomSheetDialogFragment2.onDismiss(dialog);
                    // some Code....
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this issue from 15 minutes and issue was that **i did not call** `onDismiss` of BottomSheet:

```
       override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
         if (shouldDismiss)
            onDismiss.invoke()
       }
```

**So** in your code it should be:

```
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onResume();
            MainActivity.updateMediaButtons();
            super.onDismiss(dialog); // add this line

        }
```